# From breadboard to PCB, MOSFET not able to control load

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, mosfet-driver, load

I designed a simple circuit like the one in picture to control a load:

[image]

Basically, if I'm viewing this the right way, I have a GPIO from an Arduino on the D6 point to control a MOSFET (it's actually a 30N06L one, not the 1N4007) to decide if on the load (PUMP2) I have a flow of current (the difference between the PUMP source -- 24V -- and the ground, which is on the source of the MOSFET).

This works great, when I set the GPIO to high, the load starts, when I set it to low it stops. I correctly read the value of desired voltage on the load accordingly.

It works very well when I implemented this circuit on a breadboard. Then I made a PCB out of it and this screenshot is directly from Fusion360. I populated the PCB and tested without the load, and it works. Again, GPIO to high, I do see 24V-0V on the two pins of the J2 component (a connector for the load); GPIO to low, I do see 24V-24V on the same two pins.

However, once I connect the load (an electrovalve, just two wires, nothing fancy), once I set the pin to high I read a delta voltage of about 6V (one pin stays to 24Vish, the other goes to 18Vish). Why is that? What is wrong with the PCB? What I forgot to consider? Again on the breadboard, same scheme, same load, same components, everything works just fine.

Following, the full schematic of the pcb (the breadboard has the same circuit).
[image]

Comment: Your question needs more detail. It looks like you're referring to a screenshot that hasn't been included. Images of the breadboard and PCB would be good, as well as screen shots of the PCB and full schematic from fusion.

Comment: Sorry, I think the screenshot is included (at least I can see it in my message). I would love to send pics of breadboard and PCB but they are mounted in two robots, and it's just hard to get them out easily... I will update the message adding the full schematic. Thanks!

Comment: _”MOSFET (it's actually a 30N06L one, not the 1N4007)”_ This doesn’t make sense. Please draw a schematic showing exactly what component you used and how they are connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. There was a pin on the Arduino headers on the PCB that was not welded correctly (The GND was not GND...). Re-welded and now everything works as supposed to.